# ORA-00911: invalid character ??///

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

i am trying to execute this query but i am getting ORA-00911: invalid character

```
SELECT e.empno AS “Employee ID”, e.ename AS “Employee Name”, d.deptno AS “Dept No”, 
d.dname AS “Dept Name”, d.loc AS “Dept Location” FROM emp e, dept d WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno AND e.deptno = 10;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a cut-and-paste error, but the quotes here are smart quotes, not the boring `"` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.empno AS "Employee ID", 
e.ename AS "Employee Name",
d.deptno AS "Dept No", 
d.dname AS "Dept Name", 
d.loc AS "Dept Location" 
FROM emp e, dept d WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno AND (e.deptno = 10);
```

Your double quotes are wrong. Change the quotes.

And just saying it has nothing to with error `AS` keyword is optional
you can write column aliases like this

```
e.ename "Employee Name"
```

In my opinion, it is also readable but yes depends on individuals choice.

Comment: Welcome, you may want to accept it as an answer.